# Horizontal Scrolling in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I am having some problems figuring out how to make the outlined red part in the screenshot below using Swing. It's a GUI issue. Specifically I'm doing a little project about TV Series and I don't know how to show the characters' name in a horizontal scrolling control.

Can anyone show me the extends `JTabbedPane` about my particular problem?

If I'm missing something please let me know.

[image: image excerpt]

Full screenshot: http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/5381/screenxk.png

Comment: please provide more of your own attempts and what you have tried to do. your desired result etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT`, which provides platform-specific navigation controls:

> If all the tabs do not fit within a single run the look and feel will provide a way to navigate to hidden tabs.

In contrast `JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT` provides a (default) wrapping policy:

> The tab layout policy for wrapping tabs in multiple runs when all tabs will not fit within a single run.

See [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg).